# Wastebasket/Trash bin at Optimizely Multisite

Tags: optimizely

I am wondering if someone knows how to create one Wastebasket/Trash bin per. site on Optimizely CMS? Right now we have a shared bin, and editors on different sites can delete content on another site.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no such option out of the box, but you could hook into the `Moving` event to see if `ContentReference.WasteBasket` is the target, and if so move to a different site-specific "waste basket".

However, you would have to take care of additional use-cases yourself, as the page wouldn't *technically* be in *the* waste basket.

For example, filtering out "deleted" pages in S&N queries wouldn't work as expected.

Edit: if you want to prevent deletions from the wastebasket, you could perhaps implement custom authorization in the `Deleting` event.

Comment: Yes I have been looking into that. But how do I create site-specific "Waste basket"? Don't seem to be straight forward.

Comment: There is a built-in page type called "Trash" (ID: 2), but I have no idea what happens if you would create additional pages of that type (either through code or by enabling it for edit mode) or what happens if you would click its "Empty Trash" button...

Regardless, it's not straightforward. Even if you'd create your own page type with a wastebasket icon, there are still additional events you would need to handle to manage when something is, for example, deleted from one of those site-specific wastebaskets. And you'd have to decide how to completely empty it etc.

Comment: Yeah i know. Problem is I cannot reach it. The Content Type is named "SysRecycleBin". I can reach the content type like this: 
var trashbin = _contentRepository.Get<PageData>(ContentReference.WasteBasket);
var ct = _contentTypeRepository.Load(trashbin.ContentTypeID);

But how do I create a page when type SysRecycleBin is not available in code?

Comment: You can probably create it using `contentRepository.GetDefault<PageData>(ContentReference parentLink, 2)` since `2` is the ID of the `SysRecycleBin` content type.